# Плагин для размытия любой области страницы в стиле iOS 7

Tags: jquery, плагин, css, javascript

Однажды делая свой сайт мне захотелось сделать overlay'и так же как это сделала Apple в своей iOS 7: вместо  какого либо `background` оставить его прозрачным, только лишь размыть то, что находиться позади этого div'a и иногда слегка наложить полупрозрачный цвет.

Первое место куда я пошел это были форумы, и сколько я не пытался найти что то подобное, я находил лишь не закрытые вопросы, но не ответы на них.
Поэтому остался лишь один вариант это сделать этот велосипед самому.
В результате очень долгих мучений, времени и усилий я все таки смог получить желаемый результат.

Потом мне пришла великолепная идея выложить это на GitHub.
Я его собрал в качестве плагина для `jQuery.`
[Страница](https://github.com/igolka97/blurBg) на GitHub.
[Страница](http://igolka97.github.io/blurBg/) плагина.
Очень рад буду принимать ваши pull reqest'ы, issue, отзывы, звезды и так далее)))
Не примите за рекламу, просто мне кажется что плагин действительно нужный в наше время, судя по стольким не закрытым вопросам на форумах, в большинстве своем "stackoverflow", а по другому никто о нем не узнает.
[image]

Comment: я сначала не заметил copyright и подумал что это вы написали 3к++ строк кода, а оказалось поменьше. Сложно сказать насколько он нужный, но раз сделали, то молодец.

Comment: За труды, конечно же уважуха. Но вот сколько встречал различные плагины с "размытием", применения им не нашел. Честно говоря, даже не знаю, где бы это было действительно актуальным, при том, что плагин (*если брать ваш вариант*), даже в минифицированном виде, весит 41Кб (*вся библиотека jQuery 91Кб*). Но если вдруг понадобиться - буду знать, где припаркован такой "велосипед" ;)

Comment: @Deonis , на самом деле, это отличная фитча для дизайна, overlay'и просто круть))

Comment: @Deonis  приложил скриншот, как я сделал это у себя))

Comment: Сразу понял, что тут html2canvas заюзан, а потом тупо размытие по гауссу :) Молодец конечно, но не юзабельно для динамического использования, у меня браузер думает еще секунды 2-3.

Comment: @lampa и наложение цвета! :DD  и все програмно :DD а не css)

Comment: Кажется, что можно с помощью svg фильтров такого эффекта добиться https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Applying_SVG_effects_to_HTML_content . Правда работает пока только в Firefox

Comment: Прошу прощения: можно же что то подобное организовать: http://jsfiddle.net/Ed7Ja/

Comment: Можно, только вот с [поддержкой CSS Filter Effects у браузеров][1] пока еще туговато. Кстати, вендорные префиксы **-moz, -ms** тут не пашут

   [1]:http://caniuse.com/css-filters

Comment: @igolka97, если вы используете какую либо библиотеку, то не нужно включать её в исходники, максимум положить "рядом". + html2canvas достаточно медленно штука. И как написали выше, уже давно есть CSS Filters, а там где они не поддерживаются, используем [polyfill][2]/[demo][1].

[1]: http://schepp.github.io/CSS-Filters-Polyfill/examples/static-vs-animated/static.html
[2]: https://github.com/Schepp/CSS-Filters-Polyfill

Comment: @RubaXa вы противоречите сами себе, то есть как ее положить "рядом"?? Да, можно, использовать css blur вообще везде, НО вы не сможете заблюрить ТОЛЬКО background, + вы не сможете заблюрить ТОЛЬКО часть div'a ведь css-filter  накладывается на весь div. Поэтому я использую кроссбраузерный blur, работает даже в IE, вы меня видимо не очень поняли, зачем конкретно этот плагин

Comment: @igolka, воу-воу, полегче. "Рядом" — это значит, это значит, что можно включить код сторонней библиотеки в репозиторий, разместив его например в папке /vendors/ и указав в README данную зависимость (у вас там кода ~30 строк). Про IE: нормально будет работать только в IE9, IE8 если dataURL "размытия" будет меньше 32КБ, в IE<8 ваш плагин не работает.

Comment: Привет! Как установить это на сайт?

Comment: @igolka97 вы сделали велосипед который долго собирался (но так руки и не дошли) сделать я и применить в своем проэкте [WebWin](http://webwin.hostoi.com/ "WebWin API") и хотел чтоб Aero у меня тоже было как в Windows - изучу вашу фичу и сопру наверное эффект если вы не против :) спасибо

Comment: PS: помогу с переводом: jQuery function, witch can blur the back side of transperent background of a div. A lot of people were looking for this plugin. This plugin is designed to blur the image that is an absolutely positioned layer. This was done in the style of iOS 7, which uses this concept. Так наверно лучше если вы имели ввиду "This plugin is designed to blur the image которая является абсолютно позиционированным слоем" И еще вопрос, как вы научились пользоваться GitHub по книге форумам или самостоятельно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Блурить по координатам нужно крайне редко, обычно это делается для конкретного элемента, так что css filters + polyfill самое оно;
2. Вы делаете расширение для `jQuery`, то добавьте `return this` в конец, сейчас после вызова вашего метода, невозможно продолжить цеполчку вызовов jquery-методов;
3. Внутри функции `$.fn.blurBg` вы получаете html, стирает его, а потом, на `onrendered`, заново вставляете. Это совсем плохо. Во первых, html2canvas работает асинхронно, поэтому элемент, с которым работает ваше расширение может быть за это время уже модифицирован. Во вторых, если в элементе находился тег `script`, то при использовании метода `$.fn.html` он опять будет выполнен, что может привести к нежелательным результатам, вот [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/V6BVc/);
4. Вместо метода [position](http://api.jquery.com/position/), нужно использовать [offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/);
5. Если вы пишите для `jQuery`, то лучше использовать его, а не скатываться в native код;
6. Заблуреный вариант, вставляется через background, что опять же может привести к нежелательным последствиям, если у элемента уже есть `style="background: ..."`;
7. Если ресайзить страницу, то совсем печально :]

Comment: спасибо, буду развиваться:)

Comment: Привет! Сделала все точно так же как на странице плагина, но при нажатии на кнопку Blur it появляется сообщение "Cannot access local image". Подскажи пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: С такими вопросами лучше сюда https://github.com/igolka97/blurBg/issues